# Entry URIs incorrect when using entriesService->saveEntry()

Tags: plugin-development, entries, plugin-import

I'm doing an import, and saving entries into a channel with `saveEntry()`, but the entry's URL gets saved in the wrong format.

The URL format for the channel is: `news/{postDate.year}/{slug}` and I'm saving the entry with the following code:

```
$title = utf8_encode($article['article_language_name']);
$description = utf8_encode($article['article_description']);
$text = utf8_encode($article['article_text']);
$date = new \DateTime($article['article_start'], new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Oslo'));

$entry = new EntryModel();
$entry->sectionId = $targetSectionId;
$entry->typeId = $targetEntryType;
$entry->authorId = $targetAuthorId;
$entry->postDate = $date;
$entry->enabled = true;

$entry->getContent()->title = $title;
$entry->setContentFromPost(array(
    'leadText' => $description,
    'bodyText' => $text
));

$success = craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
```

All the URIs lack the `year` param in them, but that does get included if I save the entry via the CP afterwards.

What am I doing wrong? The `postDate` seem to be in the correct format, but maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so the answer was quite simple: I was using the PHP DateTime object instead of Crafts DateTime.

Removed the `\` on this line:

```
$date = new \DateTime($article['article_start'], new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Oslo'));
```

and everything worked perfectly.